# Remote join LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, openvpn

I would like to join company LAN from my PC at home through VPS server.

Connection diagram:

[image: Network Diagram]

I only found http://www.packetix.net/en/vpn/help/remote.aspx, but it uses third party server. I want to use my own VPS. Is there any other solution ?

I've already tried openVPN, but it is too difficult for me to setup. I've only connected [Home PC] and [Company PC] to [VPS] (in VPN server role) as VPN clients, so i can use RDP to [Company PC] for working in LAN, but it is so limiting.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: VPN is the way to do this.  What problems are you having with it?  Why is it so limiting?

Comment: Ask your IT department.

Comment: When i said it is so limiting, i was meaning working through Remote  Desktop. Problem is, that VPN doesn't allow me to join LAN. VPN use own ip addresses, so i can only see (ping) VPN clients, which is in my case only one computer from company LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally done it by using SoftEther VPN Bridge. Install following software:

- [Home PC] - SoftEther VPN Client
- [VPS] - SoftEther VPN Server
- [Company PC] - SoftEther VPN Bridge

First create Virtual Hub on VPN Server. Then create cascade connection between VPN Bridge and Virtual Hub on VPN Server. Bridge your local interface on VPN Bridge. After that just join VPN Client to Virtual Hub, you will automatically receive IP from DHCP in your Company LAN and you can start working.

Comment: Hi, I've been looking for this exact solution. Can you please mention the commands you used to set those up?